# Web Scraping In R readHTMLTable error with function

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table

I'm teaching myself some basic table web scraping techniques in `R`.  But I see the error when running the function `readHTMLTable`.

> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

I am specifically trying to read the data in the second table. I've already checked the page source to make sure that the table is formatted with `<table>` and `<td>`

```
release_table <- readHTMLTable("https://www.comichron.com/monthlycomicssales/1997/
                               1997-01.html", header=TRUE, which=2,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would expect the output to mirror the text in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rvest` to get all the tables.

```
url <- "https://www.comichron.com/monthlycomicssales/1997/1997-01.html"
library(rvest)
tab <- url %>%  read_html() %>%  html_table()
```

I think what you are looking for is `tab[[1]]` or `tab[[4]]`.

Comment: Nice one Ronak!!  Very elegant!!